# exim acl_not_smtp ignored for local submissions

Tags: debian, email, exim, access-control-list

In the default **exim4** install on Debian with split configuration files I have created a custom file at `/etc/exim4/conf.d/acl/33_conf` with the following content:

```
acl_not_smtp:
  defer log_message = testing defer or deny
```

Then I am testin the setup with the `date|mail -s test remote@example.com` command on the exim box and the email gets sent no problem.

Why the email isn't deferred or denied?

Answer (score 0):

The missing configuration part is the line:

```
acl_not_smtp = acl_not_smtp
```

placed just before

```
begin acl
```

which happens to be in some other file of the default install, namely `/etc/exim4/conf.d/acl/00_exim4-config_header`

Apparently, placing it in the same file as the ACL definition itself, `/etc/exim4/conf.d/acl/33_conf`, that is *after* `begin acl`, is not allowed